# Two different definitions of Lebesgue Integral in Royden

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am a bit puzzled by the different definitions used (by Royden) in defining integral of bounded function and of non-negative function. Why didn't he use the same definition for both types of function?

---

***Definition 1:***

[image]

---

***Definition 2:***

[image]

Comment: If we tried to apply definition 1 to an arbitrary non-negative measurable function $f$, then we'd have an upper integral of $\infty$ whenever $f$ is unbounded, so would imply every unbounded function is not Lebesgue integrable.  This is a bad situation.  It's better to define the integral for "nice" functions (bounded measurable with finite support) and then use this to extend this definition to more functions (non-negative measurable)

Comment: But wikipedia simply uses the sup of simple functions as the definition. See link below

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Measure_theory

Comment: And if you are thinking about using simple functions for upper and lower integrals in definition 2, you can't: $e^{-x}1_{x>0}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ does not have finite upper integral because any simple function for your upper integral would take some positive value on some set of infinite measure.

Comment: The usual definition using positive and negative parts also has to have two separate definitions.  In either case, you need a finiteness/well-defined result first before you can extend to a larger class of functions.

Comment: I made a mistake in my first comment that became relevant with your response.  Note that $f$ is not assumed measurable in definition 1, in which context we need to talk about both a lower and upper Lebesgue integral.  When $f$ is bounded and measurable, it suffices to just consider the lower integral, which is what wikipedia does.  (actually, it only seems to work with non-negative functions because then it doesn't need finite support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. In fact, I am also comfused before about the differences of definitions of integration of nonnegative measurable function
between the definition 2 in your question and the definition in Ch18.2 of Royden Book. The definition in Ch18.2 focus on the integration
of nonnegative extended real-valued measurable function in abstract measure space in general but I think it is helpful to understand why the
definition 1 cannot be applied to the definition 2 directly.

I figures out some ways that may help to clarify the definitions.

Definition 1: f is bounded real valued, E is a measurable set of finite measure

Definition 2: f is non-negative extended real-valued, f is measurable, E is a measurable set of finite/infinite measure

To begin with, the author aims to define "Lebesgue integration" in a similar way to generalize "Riemann integration". If the upper Lebesgue integral equals to the lower Lebesgue integral,
then f is called Lebesgue integrable. So "Riemann integrability imply Lebesgue integrability" follows immediatiely for a bounded function f on
closed and bounded interval [a,b]. However, for bounded  function f on a domain E of finite measure, f may not be Lebesgue integrable since
f is not necessarily measurable. In fact, a bounded function f on a set E of finite measure is Lebesgue integrable if and only if it is measurable.

For h is bounded, measurable, of finite support and $0\leq h\leq f$ on E, the integral of h over E is defined to be
$$ \int_E h := \int_{E_0} h $$, where $E_0$ has finite measure and h = 0 on $E\setminus E_0$. This integral is defined properly and it is a
nonnegative real number. However, as stated in point 7 in def. 2, the integral $\int_E f$ is nonnegative since it is defined to
be the supremum of a set of nonnegative numbers, but the integral may be equal to $\infty$. It doesn't mean that f is intergrable, it
fails when a nonnegative measurable function that takes a positive constant value of a subset of E of infinite measure or the
value $\infty$ on a subset of E of positive measure. It provides some insights that we should consider the cases for f being
non-negative extended real-valued or E is a measurable set of infinite measure.

Now, back to your original problem.
Suppose f is non-negative extended real-valued measurable function on a set E.
Since f is measurable, the lower and upper integrals are same if f is bounded measurable on a set E of finite measure.
Supoose f is unbounded on E or f=$\infty$ on some subsets of E. We cannot find a simple function such that $f\leq \phi$, as
simple functions are not allowed to take infinite values. If we apply def. 1, then the upper intergral would be
the inf. part of empty set, $Inf(\emptyset )=\infty$. So the upper integral is discarded in defining the Lebesgue
integral of a non-negative extended real-valued measurable function f.

But there is still problem in defining the integral to be the lower Lebesgue Integral as follows:
$$\int_E f := \sup\{\int_E \varphi \:\:|\: \varphi \text{ simple and }\varphi \leq f \text{ on E } \}$$
For a simple function, it may take both of the positive and negative values. To compute the integral of
this simple function, $\infty - \infty$ may happen in the computation when $m(E)=\infty$. In this case,
only nonnegative simple functions should be considered in the definiton.
Hence, we can define the integral as follow:
$$\int_E f := \sup\{\int_E \varphi \:\:|\: \varphi \text{ simple and }0 \leq\varphi \leq f \text{ on E } \}$$

This definition agrees with the definition of the integration of nonnegative extended real-valued measurable
function in abstract measure space in Ch18.2.